# Python Twitter API v2 POST tweet returns response error 403

Tags: python, api, twitter, python-requests

I’m trying to use the Twitter API v2 to post a reply to a specific tweet id. I use the python code below which returns a response error 403 although everything seems fine about my app permissions front. What am I missing ?

Many thanks

```
import requests
URL = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?"
id = str(my_tweet_id_here)
mytext = "my_text_here"
PARAM = {"text": mytext, "reply": {"in_reply_to_tweet_id": id}}
requests.post(url = URL, params=PARAM, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer my_bearer_token_here'})
```

Comment: Is it params you want to send to the api endpoint or data? Take a close look at https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/. My wild guess is you should use data.

Comment: In the following link is an example API post request, https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/9956214/T1LMiT5U#5bd6ebb1-9d79-4456-a9a6-22ead4a41625. Please take a look at the documentations before posting a question.

Comment: You cannot post Tweets using an app-only Bearer token, you need to use user authentication.

Comment: Thanks chaps - how would you write the header for the authorization?